# Threadprivate directive after external declaration of global variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have four global variables

```
extern Vars vars;
extern Params params;
extern Workspace work;
extern Settings settings
```

that I am trying to make thread private using:

```
#pragma omp threadprivate(vars,params,work,settings)
```

I then call this function:

```
void parallelSolver(void *handle, Params *paramsIn, double* data, int dataNum){
  int i; 
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (i = 0; i < dataNum; i++) {  // Main control loop.
    Params paramsOW = load_data(*paramsIn, data, i);
    csolve(paramsOW);
  }
}
```

which loads up the data for each seperate run into paramsOW which then calls:

```
void csolve(Params paramsIn){
  set_defaults();  // Set basic algorithm parameters.
  setup_indexing();

  params = paramsIn;

  printValues(params); 

  // Solve our problem at high speed!
  long num_iters = solve();
  // Recommended: check work.converged == 1.

  //  use_solution(vars);
}
```

which calls `solve()` which calls numerous functions which use these global variables. I would rather be able pass Vars, Params, Workspace and Settings as parameters to `solve()` but the way to code is written, whose paradigm I have to follow, is that it makes us of these global variables. The error I get when trying to compile this code is:

```
$ gcc -fopenmp -shared -Wl,-soname,runSolverParalle -o runSolverParallel.so -fPIC runSolverParallel.c solver.c ldl.c matrix_support.c 
/usr/bin/ld: work: TLS reference in /tmp/cc7BbGwf.o mismatches non-TLS reference in /tmp/ccbUwz29.o
/tmp/ccbUwz29.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note I am compiling this as shared object because i am using cython and python code to send `parallelSolver` the data which instantiates it. When I eliminate the `threadprivate` deceleration it compiles and works fine (minus the race condition which is present due to all threads using the same global variables).

EDIT: Yes global variables are a cancer and it is very frustrating dealing with this code base. I did not write the underlying code and have to use it to just run one simple test case in parallel. Thus it is totally not worth my time to refactor the underlying code base. Thanks Massimiliano for reading what I stated and not jumping on the global variable hate train.

Comment: omg pragma! I think you have a typo :)

Comment: @paulm Hahahha looks like i do!

Comment: your previous question title had "pragma omg"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happened is very likely to be the effect of inserting the `threadprivate` clause not inside the header where the global variables are declared.

In fact one translation unit is seeing the variable as *non-TLS* (Thread Local Storage), while another is seeing it as *TLS*. This produces in the end a linking error.

The solution would be to insert the `threadprivate` directive in the header where those global variables are declared (and of course to use that header to declare them everywhere).

Comment: The better solution would be to not use dumb global variables.

Comment: @Puppy While I agree with you on this practice, the OP stated that he needs to follow the existing design (which uses indeed global variables).

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are a cancer. Excise them and you won't have a linking error, plus your code might actually be vaguely somewhat maintainable.